# Postgres numbering depends on the next id

Tags: postgresql-9.3

I had a scenario:

Here's my query:

```
select id, empid, dt,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt)  from
(select 21919 id,219 empid,'2018-06-01 08:41:59' dt
union all
select 21919,219,'2018-06-01 08:43:29'
union all
select 21919,219,'2018-06-01 08:50:02'
union all
select 21919,88,'2018-06-01 08:56:45'
union all
select 21919,20,'2018-06-01 11:25:55'
union all
select 21919,20,'2018-06-01 12:04:36'
union all
select 21919,88,'2018-06-01 12:05:17'
union all
select 21919,132,'2018-06-01 12:18:27'
union all
select 21919,132,'2018-06-04 13:34:53') as a
```

and my result:

[image]

But i need a result like:

[image]

Is it possible to do it in Postgres?

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I read your task right it assimple as adding an attribute for grouping?.. like:

```
select id, empid, dt,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt,empid)  from
(select 21919 id,219 empid,'2018-06-01 08:41:59' dt
union all
select 21919,219,'2018-06-01 08:43:29'
union all
select 21919,219,'2018-06-01 08:50:02'
union all
select 21919,88,'2018-06-01 08:56:45'
union all
select 21919,20,'2018-06-01 11:25:55'
union all
select 21919,20,'2018-06-01 12:04:36'
union all
select 21919,88,'2018-06-01 12:05:17'
union all
select 21919,132,'2018-06-01 12:18:27'
union all
select 21919,132,'2018-06-04 13:34:53') as a
```

Comment: I've tried to group it but how about the two 88 empid?

Comment: hm. please build a sandbox on sql fiddle to play